# CMake for protobuf library

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I make my own example following [this](https://github.com/shaochuan/cmake-protobuf-example). But I don't want to make library, but just generate header and source files from .proto file.

So, I just change:

CMakeLists.txt

```
PROJECT(rpc)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.6)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -Werror -std=c++11")

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(proto)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.cpp)
#TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main proto ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY}) #<==== I changed here
```

proto/CMakeLists.txt

```
INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)
FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HEADER message.proto)
#ADD_LIBRARY(proto ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC}) #I don't compile lib anymore
```

But it doesn't generate header and source files from .proto. So it cannot compile. I think when using `add_subdirectory`, it doesn't run command `protobuf_generate_cpp`. Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add `${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC}` directly to `ADD_EXECUTABLE(main)` call or add the following line to `proto/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_custom_target(gen_proto ALL DEPENDS ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC})
```

Comment: OK, I add the line `add_dependencies(main gen_proto)` and it works. Thanks you.